# How to read csv files from multiple zip folders located in the same directory using python?

Tags: python, csv, zip

- I have multiple zip folders named zip_folder_1, zip_folder_2, ..., zip_folder_n.
- All these zip folders are located in the same directory. Each one of these zip folders contains a csv file named "selected_file.csv".
- I need to read each one of the "selected_file.csv" located at each one of the zip folders and concatenate them into a single file

Could someone give me a hint on the required **python** code to solve this problem? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Please show us your own effort first. We can give you tips on how to improve your code, but we cant write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

This should produce `concatenated_data.csv` in your working directory, and assumes that all files in `my_data_dir` are zip files with data in them.

```
import os, numpy as np, zipfile

def add_data_to_file(new_data,file_name):
    if os.path.isfile(file_name):
        mode = 'ab'
    else:
        mode = 'wb'
    with open(file_name,mode) as f:
            np.savetxt(f,np.array([new_data]),delimiter=',')        

my_data_dir = 'C:/my/zip/data/dir/'
data_files = os.listdir(my_data_dir)
for data_file in data_files:
    full_path = os.path.join(my_data_dir,data_file)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(full_path,'r',zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip_file:
        with zip_file.open('selected_file.csv','r') as selected_file:
            data = np.loadtxt(selected_file,delimiter=",")
    add_data_to_file(data,'concatenated_data.csv')
```